# Changing the background color of an ASP DropDownList using only CSS

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, dropdownbox

I'd like to be able to change the dropdownlist background colors on my C# web app, can I do this with CSS instead of having to name each dropdown separately?

In other words, I want to avoid having to do this:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
    comboBox2.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
    comboBox3.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
    etc
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CssClass` property of the `DropDownList` and apply the class.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="dropdownlist"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" CssClass="dropdownlist"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" CssClass="dropdownlist"></asp:DropDownList>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdownlist {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Another option is to create a `Style` object and apply that to your controls in the code behind.

```
// create your style here
Style style = new Style();
style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;

// apply style to each one
comboBox1.Style = style;
comboBox2.Style = style;
comboBox3.Style = style;
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all your comboboxes and apply a css class.

```
    public void foo(List<Control> foundSofar, Control parent) 
    {

        foreach(var c in parent.Controls) 
        {
              if(c is ComboBox) //Or whatever that is you checking for 
              {
                     c.Attributes.Add("style", "color: aqua");
              }

        }  

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this a sample

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        select {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">One</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Two</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">Three</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest2" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="4">Four</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="5">Five</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="6">Six</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a `WebControl` can contain child controls, you have to be recursive about it:

```
        private void SetDropDownListBackGround(IEnumerable controls)
        {
            foreach (WebControl control in controls)
            {
                var list = control as DropDownList;
                if (list != null)
                {
                    list.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
                }

               SetDropDownListBackGround(control.Controls);
            }
        }
```

Called via

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetDropDownListBackGround(Page.Controls); //or whatever container
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but here's a nice article about how to change the `background-color` and other properties using `CSS`, even an example of one `Dropdown` with two rounded corners and the other two linear:

Source: https://parallelcodes.com/asp-net-dropdownlist-css-style/

**CSS**

```
.mydropdownlist1
{
color: #fff;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 5px 10px;
border-radius: 5px 12px;
background-color: #292929;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlItems" CssClass="mydropdownlist">
<asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="One" />
<asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="Two" />
<asp:ListItem Text="Three" Value="Three" />
<asp:ListItem Text="Four" Value="Four" />
<asp:ListItem Text="Five" Value="Five" />
<asp:ListItem Text="Six" Value="Six" />
<asp:ListItem Text="Seven" Value="Seven" />
<asp:ListItem Text="Eight" Value="Eight" />
<asp:ListItem Text="Nine" Value="Nine" />
<asp:ListItem Text="Ten" Value="Ten" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```